# separate each points element on different polygon layers on qgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I have a table called all_the_points which contains several points in rows for every element in a column, now all the elements are in the column called origin,
now each element can have several points, is possible for me to separate all points by their element on different layers on PostGIS in one view, I tried using the group by but still all my points and polygon are on one layer when I drag to my qgis.
Thank you

```
 with 
bounds as (
    select
     origin
    ,min(x) as xmin
    ,min(y) as ymin
    ,max(x) as xmax
    ,max(y) as ymax
    from all_the_points
    group by  WHERE ((all_the_points.origin)::text = '126af84e-0a9b-407d-8036-1ffc316106dd'::text);
)
select 
 origin
,st_makepolygon(st_makeline(array[
     st_makepoint(xmin,ymin)
    ,st_makepoint(xmax,ymin)
    ,st_makepoint(xmax,ymax)
    ,st_makepoint(xmin,ymax)
    ,st_makepoint(xmin,ymin)
]))
from bounds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> different layers on PostGIS in one view

No, this is not possible.

There are several options:

- have one layer, and apply a different symbology for each category in QGIS
- have one layer and filter data for a single category in QGIS. Eventually add the same layer a 2nd (and more) time and filter another category
- have a distinct view in Postgres for each layer

Comment: "have a distinct view in Postgres for each layer" can i do that with SQL

Comment: yes, just as you did. It is possible to automate it too, albeit a bit more complex. However option 1 is the most typical one, and to a lesser extent option 2. It sounds wrong to create a view for each value in a table (and it is a nightmare to maintain)

Comment: hello, please with I am trying to get my geom  column from all_the_points  table when I try to perform select it doesn't work I don't know if you can help thank you 
bounds as (
    select
     origin
    ,min(x) as xmin
    ,min(y) as ymin
    ,max(x) as xmax
    ,max(y) as ymax
    from all_the_points
    group by 1
)
select 
 origin
,st_makepolygon(st_makeline(array[
     st_makepoint(xmin,ymin)
    ,st_makepoint(xmax,ymin)
    ,st_makepoint(xmax,ymax)
    ,st_makepoint(xmin,ymax)
    ,st_makepoint(xmin,ymin)
]))
from bounds